# Do The Integrals Tend to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider the integrals $\int_1^\infty \frac{k}{x^2+k^p\cos^2x}dm(x),$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. For what $p$ do the integrands have an integrable majorant? For what $p$ do the integrals tend to $0$?

My first thought is to pull out the $k$ and then look at when the denominator gets really bad but I could use some help.

Comment: What is $m(x)?$

Comment: m is the Lebesgue integral, so dm(x) is referring to integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure. It could also be replaced with just d(x).

Comment: In my experience, $m$ is used for every measure BUT the Lebesgue measure...

Comment: Sorry about that, the notation that I've become familiar with is to use m for the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ for any standard measure. I'll be sure to add a note to the problem in case other people have the same concern.

Answer (score 1):

Pick some large constant $C.$ For $x> C k^{p/2},$ the denominator is approximately $x^2,$ so the integral is at least as big as

$$k\int_{Ck^{p/2}}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{C k^{p/2-1}}.$$ So, when $p/2 \< 1,$  (so $p<2$) the integral *diverges*, and when $p=2,$ the integral does not go to zero.

When $p \geq 2,$ that is not a problem, so we need to look at 
$$\int_1^{Ck^{p/2}} \frac{k}{x^2+k^p \cos^2 x} dx.$$ .

Now, we can write the above integral as 
$$k\sum_{l=0}^{Ck^{p/2}} \int_l^{l+1} \frac{dx}{x^2+\cos^{k^p} x}$$

The $l$-th integral in the sum is commensurate with 
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{l^2+k^p x^2} = 2\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{k^p/l})/\sqrt{l^2 k^p}.$$

Now the numerator is bounded by a constant, so the sum is bounded of something of the order $\log(k^p)/k^{p/2},$ which goes to zero.

Comment: Ok, so that gives me an integrable majorant. Thanks. Any thoughts on what values of p give me convergence?

Comment: @user114767 Actually, I made a miscalculation, watch this space for correction

Comment: @user114767 OK, it's all good now. Mod some extra calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll get to work on finishing it and will let you know if I reach a conclusion or get stuck.

Comment: So I've tried several things and can't seem to be able to calculate the integral. I thought about doing another substitution but couldn't think of what to plug in.

Comment: @user114767 See the latest version.

Comment: Ok, cool. So the integrals tend to 0 when p>2. But what can I say about a majorant?

Comment: The argument I give supplies a majorant (you can piece it together from the summands in the infinite sum).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for all of the help!